# Where's guile looking for modules

Tags: scheme

When you `guile`, it looks for modules in paths written in `~/.guile`, but in my case in still doesn't find all the modules.
Where else can it be looking?

Answer (score 1):

The directories Guile searches for modules in are specified in the `%load-path` variable. You can add to this by setting the `GUILE_LOAD_PATH` environment variable (you can add multiple directories by using a colon between each).

Comment: Oh. Thanks, I'll try this and report with results.

Comment: Ok, it turned out that you can just run `guile` and then type `%load-path` and guile would print out a rather helpful list of places it uses to look for modules.